# Число которое загадал пользователь

Tags: java

не ругайте и не кидайте камнями, но меня заклинило. код работает "как бы" , но вот если он доходит до диапазона например 66 - 67 или доходит до предела (1 или 100), он дальше генерирует числа 67 или 1 с 100, и получается что зависает. Уже и считал диапазон, что бы разница между мин и мах была <1, и рандомное число, что генерируется, было в диапазоне не больше чем на один, но все  не хочет работать...кто может подсказать??

```
public class Ugadaj {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Загадай число от 1 до 100 и я его удадаю. Как тебя зовут? ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        int max = 100;
        int min = 1;
        int scor = 0;
        int random = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * max);
        System.out.println("Очень приятно "+name+". Число которое Ты загадал - " + random  + " ? (1-ДА,0-НЕТ)");
        int i = in.nextInt();
        while(i!=1) {
            System.out.println("Твоё число больше " + random + "? (1-ДА,0-НЕТ)");
            i = in.nextInt();
            if (i == 1) {
                min = random + 1;
                int random2 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
                random = random2;
                scor++;
                System.out.println("Ты загал число " + random + " ? (1-ДА,0-НЕТ)" + " Сейчас диапозон : "
                        + min + " - " + max);
                i = in.nextInt();
            } else {
                max = random - 1;
                int random2 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
                random = random2;
                scor++;
                System.out.println("Ты загал число " + random + " ? (1-ДА,0-НЕТ)" + " Сейчас диапозон : "
                        + min + " - " + max);
                i = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Твоё число было " + random + " . Угаданно с " + scor + " попыток");
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем у Вас число генерируется рандомом в цикле? Это же бинарный поиск - там нужно половинить диапазоны.

Answer (score 0):

// вот пример моего старенького кода. глянь может пригодиться.Код рабочий!

package Game;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Б_М1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);          /* ввод с клавиатуры 
                                                         * сохраняет его в перем.
                                                         */   
        String newGame ="";                             // перем. повторения 
                                                        // цикла do   
        int n2 = (0);                                   // переменная подсчета 
                                                        // ходов
// основной цикл ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        do {                                          
      int N1 = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);   // генерация случайного числа 
                                                 // от 0 до 100,9999
                //System.out.println(N1);        // сгенерированное число
            int guess = 0;                       // переменная , хранения ответов
            System.out.println("Здравствуй мой господин!"); 

// ЦИКЛ УГАДЫВАНИЯ WHILE ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            while (guess != N1) {                
                System.out.println("введи число от 0 до 100:");
                guess = scan.nextInt();  // ожидает следующее значение переменной 
                                         // ответа введенное пользователем
                if (guess < N1) 
                System.out.println(guess + " мало, соберись!");
                else if (guess > N1)     // проверяет второе условие
                        System.out.println(guess + " дохрена, соберись!");
                else                     // проверяет третье условие
                        System.out.println(guess + ". Это победа мой господин!");
// ЦИКЛ подсчета ходов /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                n2 = (++n2);
                    switch (n2) {
                    case 1,2,3,4:
                        System.out.println("   Это " + n2 + " попытка!");
                    break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("   Это " + n2 + " попытка!");
                        System.out.println("Ну ты... долго!!!");
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("ещё разочек? (Y/N)");
            newGame = scan.next();           // сканирует ввод с клавиатуры 
                                             // символа или группы символов 
        } while (newGame.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));       // закрытие цикла do,  
                                        // если ввести "y" цикл возобновится
        System.out.println("Чао мой господин!");
        scan.close();  // закрыть поток ввода
    }

}
```